# Application of Kolmogorov three series theorem in Homework Problem

Tags: probability

I have a homework problem which I encounter some difficulty in. I sincerely hope you all can assist me in attempting the following question:

Given a sequence of i.i.d random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with the condition that $E[|X_1|^{\alpha}]<\infty$ for $0<\alpha<1$. Here $E$ refers to the expectation. I am therefore tasked to apply the Kolmogorov's three series theorem to prove that ${{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}\over {n^{{1} \over {\alpha}}}}\rightarrow0$ almost surely.

I am being advised to apply Borel Cantelli Lemma to do some truncation to the summation in the question. However, I have no idea how to begin with.

Kindly advise me on the details as I am new to modern Probability Theory.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: "Even though the homework has been submitted"... Thus you may want to post here what you submitted, so that people may see whether you erred, and where, if you did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, recall that Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem (K3ST) is used to prove that the
sum of independent random variables $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i$ converges a.s. ("a.s." means "almost surely"), i. e., $S_1+\cdots +S_n$ converges a.s. But for this problem, you are asked to prove that $n^{-1/\alpha} (X_1 + \cdots + X_n)\to 0$ a.s. At first glance, it seems like the conclusion of K3ST looks nothing like what we want to prove and so won't be useful. Kronecker's Lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma) will provide the required bridge from K3ST to the conclusion we wish to prove.

Define the random variable $S_n$ to be
$$
S_n = \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}} X_n.
$$
We will check the three conditions of K3ST for $S_n$. This will allow us to conclude $S_1+\cdots+S_n$ converges a.s. Simple application of Kronecker's Lemma with $S_n$ and the constant sequence $n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ will then allow us to conclude $n^{-1/\alpha} (X_1 + \cdots + X_n)\to 0$ a.s.

For brevity, define the random variable $C_n$ as
$$
C_n = \lceil|X_n|^{\alpha}\rceil.
$$
Also, define
$$
p_i = \mathbb{P}(C_n = i)
$$
for all integers $i\ge 0$. Note that $p_i$ does not depend on $n$, since $X_n$ and therefore $S_n$ and $C_n$ are i.i.d.

By Minkowski's inequality  and the fact that $C_n\le |X_n|^{\alpha} + 1$, we conclude $\mathbb{E}(C_n) < \infty$.

We now verify K3ST for $S_n$.

**Series 1** We must verify that $\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{P}(|S_n| > 1) < +\infty$. Observe
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{P}(|S_n| > 1) &\le& \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{P} (|X_n| > n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}) \\
&=& \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{P} (|X_n|^{\alpha} > n) \\
&\le& \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{P} (C_n > n) \\
&=& \sum_{n\ge 1} \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} p_i \\
&=& \sum_{i\ge 2} (i-1) p_i\\
&\le& \mathbb{E}(C_n) < \infty.
\end{eqnarray}

**Series 2** We need to show $\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(S_n 1_{|S_n|\le 1})$ converges. One can show this by proving
$$
(*)\ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(|S_n| 1_{|S_n|\le 1}) < \infty.
$$
To show this, first note
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}(|X_n| 1_{|X_n|\le n^{1/\alpha}}) &=& \mathbb{E}(|X_n| 1_{|X_n|^{\alpha}\le n}) \\
&\le& \mathbb{E}(C_n^{1/\alpha} 1_{C_n\le n}) \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^n i^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} p_i.
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(|S_n| 1_{|S_n|\le 1}) &=& \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}} \mathbb{E}(|X_n| 1_{|X_n|\le n^{1/\alpha}}) \\
&\le& \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}} \sum_{i=1}^n i^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} p_i \\
&=& \sum_{i\ge 1} \left(\sum_{n\ge i} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\right) \ i^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} p_i \\
&\le& K \sum_{i\ge 1} i p_i = K \mathbb{E}(C_n) < \infty.
\end{eqnarray}
Here, $K$ is a finite constant, independent of $i$, such that
$$
\sum_{n\ge i} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}} \le \frac{K}{i^{\frac{1}{\alpha} - 1}}.
$$

**Series 3** We must show $\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathrm{Var}(S_n 1_{|S_n|\le 1}) < \infty$. Given $(*)$ above, this is easy:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathrm{Var}(S_n 1_{|S_n|\le 1}) &\le& \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(S^2_n 1_{|S_n|\le 1}) \\
&\le& \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(|S_n| 1_{|S_n|\le 1}) < \infty.
\end{eqnarray}

And we're done.